# How do I sum predictions produced from multiple regression models

Tags: regression, prediction

I work for a museum and I've been tasked with building a method to predict our attendance.  I've created different multiple regression models for each unique attendance segment (i.e. tourists vs locals).  Each model predicts the the weekly attendance for a given segment.

What I'm trying to figure out is, how do I summarize the model predictions both:
a) across models for a given week: i.e. I expect that in week 1 we will have 500 local visitors and 1000 tourists for a total of 1500 visitors with a prediction interval of +- z.
b) longitudinally within a model: i.e. I expect that we will have 25,000 local visitors this year with a prediction interval of +- z.

I'm asking this independent of software, however, I used MiniTab to create the regression models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the errors in quadrature, see for instance [this link](http://www.rit.edu/~w-uphysi/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html). For instance:

```
total_error = sqrt(sig_1^2 + sig_2^2 + sig_3^2 ...)
```

Comment: Incase this link ceases to exist, the correct answer is to convert the SD back to the variance, add the variances and take the square root to convert back to the correct units.